# Error in Python menu using a function as the?

Tags: python, menu, try-catch

I tried to do it again but I can not find what the error is, help :C

The idea is to make a menu with the help of the option option to later use it again

```
def Opcion():
    try:
        op = int(input("Que Ejercicio quieres hacer?\n"))
        if(op<=0):
            print("NO")
            Opcion()
        elif(op>=3):
            print("NO")
            Opcion()
    except:
            print ("Ingrese un numero del 1 al 11 plz")
            Opcion()
            pass
def menu():
        print("1. Ejercicio 1")
        print("2. Ejercicio 2")
        print("3. Ejercicio 3")

        Opcion()
        if(op==1):
            print("1. Ejercicio 1")
        if(op==2):
            print("1. Ejercicio 2")
        if(op==3):
            print("Haz salido")
menu()
```

use the function option for the menu
this is the actual error

```
File "prueba.py", line 49, in <module>
menu()
File "prueba.py", line 27, in menu
if(op==1):
NameError: name 'op' is not defined
```

Comment: You need to define `op`

Comment: op is a local variable of function `Opcion` you should return this variable in Opcion function and the assign in the `menu` function

Comment: Also, you are trying to call `Opcion()` from `Opcion()`... which is not going to work. Are you trying to **loop** `Opcion()` until the user inputs a valid option?

Comment: Gino Mempin Yes, I'm trying that,  
already try with return

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

You need to return the parameter if you want to get it from function. And you can use 'While' loop instead of keep calling the function.

```
def Opcion():

    while 1:
        try:
            op = int(input("Que Ejercicio quieres hacer?\n"))
            if(op<=0):
                print("NO")

            elif(op>=3):
                print("NO")
            else:
                break
        except:
            print ("Ingrese un numero del 1 al 11 plz\n")

    return op
def menu():
        print("1. Ejercicio 1")
        print("2. Ejercicio 2")
        print("3. Ejercicio 3")
        op = Opcion()
        if(op==1):
            print("1. Ejercicio 1")
        if(op==2):
            print("1. Ejercicio 2")
        if(op==3):
            print("Haz salido")
menu()
```

The above code keeps asking for user input unless they enter integers between 1-3. Don't know whether it matches your desired result or not. But hope you can learn something from it. Cheers:)